# Generating random outputs with seed value defined and changed at run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, random

I am writing a random names generator in C#. 
It is a WPF application written in Visual Studio 2015.

A WPF Window screenshot to illustrate:

[image: A WPF Window screenshot to illustrate]

The trouble I have occurs when I try to generate names from seed values set by the user at run-time. Before, I had the random method, that supplied all of the names generating logic, declared as static and the seed value was unchanged for the whole time the program ran. This worked well, generating different output every time I clicked Generate Name button.

I wanted, however, to add the functionality of changing the seed number of the built-in random method when the program runs. In order to do this, I had to change the declaration to non-static and make the Random a part of the NamesGenerator object instance. Now, every time I change the seed value, a different name is created as it should, but when I leave the seed value the same, each click on the Generate Name button creates the same output. (You can see this on the WPF Window screenshot.)

What I am trying to end up with is a program that can generate the same outputs (hence I am using seed values), but I want for each seed value to have a set of names available (as there was when the random method was static) not just one name generated all the time.

I am not sure this is even possible, and if it is, it is clearly out of my league for now, that is why I am asking for help. I tried to search for similar issues on the web and SO, but I could not find anything helpful.

Here, I supply some of my code:

```
class NamesGenerator
{
   Random randomNumber; //I tried to have this static and non-static, to no avail

...NAMES GENERATING CODE...

   //SetSeedValue is called from the WPF Window and instantiates a new Random instance with seed value. 
   public void SetSeedValue(int seedValue)
        {
            randomNumber = new Random(seedValue); 
        }
   public string GenerateName()
    {
        // determines if the name is male or female (unlike in English, there is a whole lot of differences in Russian related to this)
        bool genderValue = equalDistributionMechanism(); // returns true if the name is masculine, false if it is not

        string name;

        name = makeTestName((randomNumber.Next(1, 2)), genderValue); //first name

        name += " " + makeTestName((randomNumber.Next(1, 2)), genderValue) 
               + addSuffix((randomNumber.Next(1, 7)), gender: genderValue); //last name

            return name;
        }
```

My thought on how to solve my problem would be to check if randomNumber has already been instantiated with given seedValue, and if yes, not create another instance of randomNumber in SetSeedValue method, but I have no idea on how to check for this.

A WPF code I am using:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    NamesGenerator namesGenerator = new NamesGenerator();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GenerateNameButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int seedValue;

        try
        {
            seedValue = int.Parse(SeedNumberTextBox.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid seed number. Try again.", "Invalid Seed Number", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            return;
        }

        namesGenerator.SetSeedValue(seedValue);
        AddNewName(namesGenerator.GenerateName());
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time and any thoughts on how to accomplish this :).

**EDIT:**
Adding the GenerateName method due to a request from Hüseyin BurakKaradag.

Comment: can you share namesGeneator.GenerateName()  method?

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Setting seed will change sequence of generated pseudo-random numbers which seem at least partially what you want... Could you please remove all unrelated WPF code from your sample and have just one class/function that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Every time you hit the button you are setting the seed value to the number in the textbox so you get the same 'random' value unless you change the number in the textbox. Add a button to set the seed value only or save the current seed value and only create a new Random when it changes.

Comment: I think you edited out the problem code.

Comment: I edited my question. 
What I am asking (and sorry for being unclear) is to be able to generate a list of random names for every seed value. Before, when I had eg. seed value 3, every time I called random method a new name was generated for that seed value. Now, whenever I call the GenerateName method with seed value 3, the same name is constructed.

Comment: J.H. Thank you. I tried having a separate button for saving the seed value and it works perfectly.

Comment: LucidFox - You're welcome. I was typing an answer since it seemed like you didn't get what I was saying. Would you like me to finish the answer?

Comment: Yes please, I will gladly upvote. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you edited your question, you had:

```
private void GenerateNameButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int seedValue;

        try
        {
            seedValue = int.Parse(SeedNumberTextBox.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid seed number. Try again.", "Invalid Seed Number", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            return;
        }

        namesGenerator.SetSeedValue(seedValue);
        AddNewName(namesGenerator.GenerateName());
    }
```

So, every time the button was pressed, the seed value was set to the same value (unless the textbox text was changed, that is). This causes Random to generate the same number over and over.

You can either add a button that sets the seed value and not set the seed value in the generate names button or if you want to keep the single button then cache the current seed value and only create a new Random when it changes. Like this:

```
class NamesGenerator
{
    Random randomNumber;
    int currentSeed = -1;

    public void SetSeedValue(int seedValue)
    {
        if (currentSeed == seedValue)
            return;
        currentSeed = seedValue;
        randomNumber = new Random(seedValue);
    }
}
```

Or cache the TextBox's text so you don't have to parse it each button press.